# How to fix Response: {type: "cors"} when trying to create payment through paypal api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, cors, fetch

I'm testing fetch API to create a payment with PayPal plus

My first fetch function works correctly, I do an Oauth to get the bearer token so I can get my access_token to make my payment post

```
callPaypal = async () => {
    try {
      const details = {
        grant_type: "client_credentials"
      };
      var formBody = [];
      for (var property in details) {
        var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
        var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
        formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
      }
      formBody = formBody.join("&");
      var request = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization:
            "Basic <secrets>",
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        body: formBody
      };
      const res = await fetch("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", request);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      const access_token = data.access_token;
      this.makePaymentPaypal(access_token);
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

```
makePaymentPaypal = async (access_token) => {
    try {
      var request = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          intent: "sale",
          application_context: {
            shipping_preference: "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
          },
          payer: {
            payment_method: "paypal",
            payer_info: {
              billing_address: {
                line1: "Mariano Escobedo 476 piso 14",
                line2: "Anzures, Miguel Hidalgo",
                city: "Mexico DF",
                country_code: "MX",
                postal_code: "11590",
                state: "DF"
              }
            }
          },
          transactions: [
            {
              amount: {
                currency: "MXN",
                total: "522.00",
                details: {
                  subtotal: "522.00"
                }
              },
              description: "Pedido en Envia Flores",
              payment_options: {
                allowed_payment_method: "IMMEDIATE_PAY"
              },
              invoice_number: "94234212",
              item_list: {
                items: [
                  {
                    name: "Arreglo de flores",
                    description: "Amigo secreto",
                    quantity: "1",
                    price: "290.00",
                    sku: "sku01",
                    currency: "MXN"
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Ilumina su dia",
                    description: "Ilumina su dia",
                    quantity: "1",
                    price: "290.00",
                    sku: "sku02",
                    currency: "MXN"
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Descuento",
                    description: "Descuento",
                    quantity: "1",
                    price: "-58.00",
                    sku: "skiu12",
                    currency: "MXN"
                  }
                ],
                shipping_address: {
                  recipient_name: "Costumer Costumer",
                  line1: "Mariano Escobedo 476 piso 14",
                  line2: "Anzures, Miguel Hidalgo",
                  city: "Mexico DF",
                  country_code: "MX",
                  postal_code: "11590",
                  state: "DF",
                  phone: "54545454"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          redirect_urls: {
            cancel_url: "https://www.example.com",
            return_url: "https://www.example.com"
          }
        })
      };
      const res = await fetch("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment", request, {
        mode: "no-cors"
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

Edited question because I already solved it, code below was missing, I needed to convert response to json.

```
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data)
```

old error message before adding this new code was:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment", redirected: false, status: 201, ok: true, …}
```

Answer (score 20):

I finally found the solution, the code was ok, what was missing was that the response needed to be transformed with json() like this:

```
  const res = await fetch("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment", request);
  var data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
```

after I added res.json to the response, I can read it properly.

Comment: How   `var data = await res.json();` helped in removing cors ? I am facing same issue

Comment: @NoobCoder the missing key here, was that you need to `await` the `var data` portion as well. That or use .then(res => res.json) on the original like `const res = `. Basically you get a response back without the data, since the Promise is not being waited for.

Comment: @NoobCoder if you watch closely the response, it says:
```type: "cors"```
but the status is 
```status: 201``` 
that's the first clue that our request succeeded and the problem is elsewhere in this specific case.

so it was not a CORS issue, it just happens the response was of type CORS which stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

when the root problem is that the server is missing the CORS headers, the error message will look something like: 
```cors error the request has been blocked because of the cors policy```